# How to create an output under Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two table say with table name "Books" , "Params" as

[Input tables are attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMCO9.jpg)

I need an output as shown in the below figure:

[I need an output as in below format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxuXa.jpg)

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? Also, add data and expected output as text (**not images**)

Comment: Also, please add your current code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can pivot the params table using aggregation and left join it with the books table like this:

```
select b.*, p.author, p.issue_date
from books b
left join (
    select id,
        max(case when Attr_id = 'Author' then Others end) as author,
        max(case when Attr_id = 'Issue Date' then Others end) as issue_date
    from params
    group by id
    ) p on b.id = p.id
order by id;
```

Produces:

```
id  name    author  issue_date
101 Sumit   Bhagat  
102 Ben     Sinha   2005
103 Amit
```